# Avro schema not respecting alias in schema definition

Tags: python, avro

Avro schema `schema.avsc`:

```
{
    "namespace": "standard",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "agent",
    "aliases":["agents"],
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "id",
            "type": ["string", "null"]
        },
        {
            "name": "name",
            "type": ["string", "null"],
            "aliases":["title", "nickname"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Python script `main.py`:

```
from fastavro import writer, reader
from fastavro.schema import load_schema

schema = load_schema('schema.avsc')
avro_data = 'agent.avro'
data = jsonlines.open('data.jsonl')

with open(avro_data, 'wb') as fout:
    writer(fout, schema, data, validator=True)

with open(avro_data, 'rb') as fin:
    for i in reader(fin, schema):
        print(i)
```

When my json lines `data.jsonl` file looks like this:

```
{"id":"1","name":"foo"}
{"id":"2","name":"bar"}
```

My python script returns:

```
{'id': '1', 'name': 'foo'}
{'id': '2', 'name': 'bar'}
```

However, if my json lines `data.jsonl` file looks like this:

```
{"id":"1","title":"foo"}
{"id":"2","title":"bar"}
```

My python script returns:

```
{'id': '1', 'name': None}
{'id': '2', 'name': None}
```

Any idea why the `name` column isn't respecting the `aliases` attribute I've defined in the avro schema file for that particular field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aliases are used when you have data written with an old schema that you want to read with a new schema. Your example only uses one schema, so aliases wouldn't work with just a single schema.

Let's use the following two schemas in an example. Here's an "old" schema which uses the `title` field:

`old_schema.avsc`

```
{
    "namespace": "standard",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "agent",
    "aliases":["agents"],
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "id",
            "type": ["string", "null"]
        },
        {
            "name": "title",
            "type": ["string", "null"]
        }
    ]
}
```

And a new schema where we want the new `name` field to be an alias of the old `title` field:

`new_schema.avsc`

```
{
    "namespace": "standard",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "agent",
    "aliases":["agents"],
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "id",
            "type": ["string", "null"]
        },
        {
            "name": "name",
            "type": ["string", "null"],
            "aliases":["title"]
        }
    ]
}
```

If we use your second `data.jsonl` which looks like this:

```
{"id":"1","title":"foo"}
{"id":"2","title":"bar"}
```

Then we can use a slightly modified version of your `main.py` so that the data is written with the old schema and then the new schema is passed to the `reader` so that the aliases are respected:

```py
from fastavro import writer, reader
from fastavro.schema import load_schema
import jsonlines

old_schema = load_schema('old_schema.avsc')
new_schema = load_schema('new_schema.avsc')
avro_data = 'agent.avro'
data = jsonlines.open('data.jsonl')

# Data is writen with old schema
with open(avro_data, 'wb') as fout:
    writer(fout, old_schema, data, validator=True)

# And read with new schema
with open(avro_data, 'rb') as fin:
    for i in reader(fin, new_schema):
        print(i)
```

Now the output is correct:

```
{'id': '1', 'name': 'foo'}
{'id': '2', 'name': 'bar'}
```